# Checking if an element has a specific ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm still new with JavaScript and jQuery.

I'm trying to check to see if this certain html code has an element with a specific ID. For example:

```
<select id="id1">...</select>
<select id="id2">...</select>
```

How do I check to see if a select element has a specific ID (or if it exists) in this example?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use jQuery you could do

```
$('#id1').length > 0 // 'id1' is control id and # is required to select by id with jQuery
```

jQuery won't simplify your life in this particular case though. With plain Javascript you could simply do

```
document.getElementById('id1') != null
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this

```
if (document.getElementById("id1")) {
    // do something
}
```

and if you want to search only in child elements of given node use querySelector:

```
if (yourElement.querySelector("#id1")) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if an element exists:

```
jQuery("#yourid").size() // Will return 0 if doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi brother you can do a simple test like this :

```
$(function(){
    if($('element').attr('id')=='id1'){
        //select has id == 'id1'
    }else{
       //select has id != 'id1'
    }
});
```

'element' in your case is 'select'.

Comment: Would it be better to use === instead of ==? I've heard == can be a little finicky sometimes.

Comment: Just == should do the work, the === will add condition in type also, but we don't need it here. (y)

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up doing this a different way due to the nature of my situation--on one page, the element of the ID was a read-only textbox. On another, the element of the same ID was a select. So I did the following:

```
var elem = document.GetElementById(id);
if (elem.nodeName === 'SELECT') {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, this will find all the *select* elements with the id you're querying.

```
$("select #id1").length();
```

Additionally, this works

```
$("select[id='id2']").length();
```